# Use a server between clients and sentry.io

Tags: flutter, docker, server, proxy, sentry

Sentry.io is restricted in my country and I can not use sentry.io dsn in my application for clients. is there any way to use a proxy tunnel between my clients and sentry.io ?
which one would be better for my situation, sentry relay or sentry self-hosted?

Comment: Some SDKs already offer a built-in `tunnel` support https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/configuration/options/#tunnel
Some SDKs also offer a built-in `proxy` support, https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/configuration/options/#http-proxy

Comment: You could also run your own Relay https://github.com/getsentry/relay